# extending a class and implementing an interface

Tags: actionscript-3, class, interface

I am creating objects for a game, they are all sprites. but I also want them to implement an interface. Is it possible to do both ? If not, how can i have an object have the capabilities of a sprite and also have it implement an interface. I am wanting to create another class that checks all my objects to see what datatype they are and evaluate them accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible for all ActionScript objects to *both* implement an interface *and* extend a class.  Here's an example:

```
public class RedZoid extends Sprite implements IColoredZoid
```

Furthermore, the `is` keyword works with interface implementations:

```
var z1:RedZoid = new RedZoid();
if (z1 is IColoredZoid) {
  // This branch will be hit, since the interface is implemented
}
```

Comment: what about the other way around. z1:IColoredZoid, then have a if statement chcek to see if z1 is Redzoid. lets just say that z1 is passed through a method.